# Symfony 4 Form FileType constraint problem

Tags: forms, symfony4, symfony-forms

I'm making a Symfony form upload with the UploadType.
My entity consists of multiple collections, each entity uses the same upload field.
Therefore i'm trying to handle the upload/move logic in the form event handler instead of
handle it in the controller, like discribed in https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/controller/upload_file.html#using-a-doctrine-listener)

But after submitting the form, the image is moved but the form field triggers the error

```
The file could not be uploaded.
```

It look likes the constraint new File with mineTypes causes this error but then you would expect a other error message. But each time i removed the constraint the form shows now errors, but i need server validation.
When i removed the eventListener the form is working again, but then the image is not uploaded.

Could someone explain this behaviour

```
$builder->add('uploadedFile', FileType::class, array(
    'label' => 'context.upload.label',
    'required' => false,
    'constraints' => array(
        new File(array(
            'mimeTypes' => array(
                'image/jpeg'
            ),
        ))
    ),
    'attr'     => [
        'accept' => 'image/*',
        'class' => '_image_upload form-control'
    ],
    'block_prefix' => '_context_upload',
));

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($options)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if($data instanceof Context) {
            if(null !== $folder = $this->folderManager->getFirst(new ManagerData(array('id' => $options['folder_id'])))) {
                // new upload
                /** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
                $uploadedFile = $form->get('uploadedFile')->getData();

                if($uploadedFile) {
                    $originalFilename = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);

                    // this is needed to safely include the file name as part of the URL
                    $safeFilename = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [^A-Za-z0-9_] remove; Lower()', $originalFilename);
                    $unique = uniqid();
                    $extension = $uploadedFile->guessExtension();
                    $mineType = $uploadedFile->getMimeType();
                    $newFilename = sprintf('%s-%s.%s', $safeFilename, $unique, $extension);

                    // move the file
                    try {
                        $uploadPath = sprintf('%s/%s', $this->params->get('inspection_upload_directory'), $extension);
                        $uploadedFile->move($uploadPath, $newFilename);

                        $upload = new BaseUpload();
                        $upload->setFolder($folder);
                        $upload->setFilename(sprintf('%s-%s', $safeFilename, $unique));
                        $upload->setExtension($extension);
                        $upload->setMimeType($mineType);

                        $data->setUpload($upload);
                    } catch(FileException $e) {
                        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```